# How to get a SELECT DISTINCT on a SelectMulti query in ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to get a distinct result set of tuples, but the Distinct never gets added to query.

Example

```
  List<Tuple<Alpha, Beta>> results;

  var q = dbConn.From<Alpha>()
          .Join<Alpha, Beta>((a, b) => a.Id == b.AlphaId)
          ... 
          ... more joins and Wheres
          ...
          .SelectDistinct();

  results = dbConn.SelectMulti<Alpha, Beta>(q);
```

Adding the SelectDistinct, or not, make no difference to the outputted SQL and hence results.

How do I get SelectMulti to work with Distinct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added support for this in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/c47ec9163b3c6335d3d443ff15fa5d5a849cf7f1) where if `.SelectDistinct()` is used in the `SqlExpression<T>` then it will execute the SQL query using `SELECT DISTINCT`, e.g:

```
var results = dbConn.SelectMulti<Alpha, Beta>(q.SelectDistinct());
```

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thank you for the superb speed of response, and solving the problem. Bravo!

Comment: @mythz, is v5.4.1 stable?

Comment: @jgozal yeah it's built by the same CI and passes the same test suite as the official NuGet packages.

Comment: Is there any reason why q = q.SelectDistinct() won't save the "distinct" flag? E.g. `SelectMany<A,B>(q.SelectDistinct())` works, but not `q = q.SelectDistinct(); SelectMany<A,B>(q);`     https://gist.cafe/8aa9176654b0abfa5818820b00cd9041